# How to get data using foreign key

Tags: database, oracle-sqldeveloper

Suppose I have two tables:

```
user{
    user_id:             primary key
    password:
          .
          .
          .
}

inbox{
    user_id:             foreign key
    message:
}
```

I want to get a password and message of a user_id. How would I do that using foreign_key?

Answer (score 0):

You have to join the two columns by USER_ID, and in the select you just put the fields you want.

Comment: Then why should I use foreign key ? Does it not related to select statement ? And Thanks for quick reply

Comment: Because you are relating you data by ID, so you won't have duplicate data... That's the point of using foreign keys. The whole data is in the main table, and to refer that data, you relate it with the id. So, you join the two tables and get only the data you care, not the Whole main table